# Need help when reading .sam file of cocos2D game

Tags: ida, decryption, apk

so recently I tried to reverse a dead game apk to get their animation cause it's so unique that me and my friend want to remake it.

But it took so long to just take each part of the image and combine it to get a frame of an animation.

So I looked up the lua code which handles the .sam file that holds all the data to automatically combine it and make animation from the origin image.

But then it takes me to the libgame.so zcAnimNode.create function and then to the zcAnimNode.init and stuff the thing is I'm not really good at reading assembly so I can't figure out how they read the .swf.sam file and get the data from it, can somebody help me with it, please.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id=1rV9BNKJGYH-2MQoB_r4nMabTlpDqLadd&export=download&confirm=t&uuid=a6b7b8d8-3e0c-4731-97df-a12d86e1a652&at=AB6BwCDLpWPDpXDl4R0Kp6OvgGat:1701605917976)'s all the stuff like the decrypted lua file thanks to this guy [here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/32272/44679) and apk, decompiled java source code, libgame.so file, even the OBB file which contains origin image and .swf.sam file and .plist file (i actually copy 1 animation to the lib folder so if u don't want to get it from obb file just use that one to test your code when read assembly)